# ML.Net Model Builder 2022 updates

Tags: ml.net, visual-studio-2022

Every time I update VS 2022, I get a notification that ML.Net Model builder needs an update...  However its the same version that keeps getting re-updated.

[image]

It appears that with every VS 2022 I have to udpate this extension to the same version over and over again.  This screenshot is one I took two days ago on the 14th (vs 2022 17.0.3)  and today I did the VS 2022 17.0.4 update and low and behold I now have to update ML.Net and its the same version changes as it was 2 days ago and earlier....

Is this a weird bug with VS 2022?

***12/20/2021*** This happened again... the PKGDEF extension required an update and during that update ML.NET was downgraded again and so required another ML.NET update back to the 16.7.6.2152701 version.  This is really getting annoying...

***12/22/2021*** This happened again... the PKGDEF extension required an update and during that update ML.NET was downgraded again and so required another ML.NET update back to the 16.7.6.2152701 version.

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Kixoka 

Sorry to hear you're running into this issue. Can you please open this as an issue on the [Model Builder GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder). 

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder

Thanks.

Comment: @LuisQuintanilla ... sure can... thanks!

Comment: @Kixoka if you created an issue, will you post the link here?

Comment: I think it's this one:
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder/issues/1952

Comment: That was the issue i posted in GitHub correct,,,,